# rails model where boolean value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is my code for checking  boolean (i am using sqlite)

```
Swimming::Classstudent.where("swimming_classtimes.date >= ? and student_id = ? and deleted = 'f'",current_date,student_id)
```

Apparently it looks ugly.

I tried

```
Swimming::Classstudent.where("swimming_classtimes.date >= ? and student_id = ? and deleted = 0 ",current_date,student_id)
```

and

```
Swimming::Classstudent.where("swimming_classtimes.date >= ? and student_id = ? and deleted = false ",current_date,student_id)
```

They both are not working.  Is there a better way to check boolean with `where` in rails ?

Comment: try this : 
Swimming::Classstudent.where("swimming_classtimes.date >= ? and student_id = ?",current_date,student_id).where(:deleted => false)

or this : 
Swimming::Classstudent.where("swimming_classtimes.date >= ? and student_id = ? and deleted = ? ",current_date,student_id, false)

Comment: @Taiki I have tried second one it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion would be to breakdown your query into reusable scopes. Code below is for Rails 4.

```
class Classstudent

  scope :after_or_on, -> (date) { where("swimming_classtimes.date >= ?", date) }

  scope :for_student, -> (id) { where(student_id: id) }

  scope :active, -> { where(deleted: false) }

end
```

Usage:

```
Swimming::Classstudent.after_or_on(current_date).for_student(student_id).active
```

This is questionable because I don't really have your application in front of me. Personally, I don't like `swimming_classtimes` join table in the `after_or_on` scope. Point is, when your queries start to get out of hand, extract the different clauses into scopes. It will make for much more readable, flexible, and testable code.

** might need a bit of tweaking so let me know if you decide to go this route and have any trouble **